# inline_message_id pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot)

Tags: python, telebot

python3
pyTelegramBotAPI(telebot)
Здравствуйте, читал документацию, но не понимаю для чего нужен inline_message_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишу ботов телеграм уже достаточно давно и никогда не сталкивался с подобным, хоть и использовал inline режим.

Возможно, дело в библиотеке которую я использую. По моему мнению, эта библиотека будет лучше telebot.

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

Comment: Спасибо, задам еще один вопрос. У меня есть 2 функции, и к примеру у каждого callback_data = '1', как сделать чтобы обработчик не путался?Например, можно ли указать "id" inline-кнопки, или как узнать с какой функции пришел запрос на обработчик?

Comment: Лучше делать callback data с разными значениями. Т.е для кнопок оплаты 500:purchase 200:purchase и так далее

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120196/Проблема-с-callback-inline-telebot
Тут я расписал подробнее

Answer (score 0):

Из документации:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery

> inline_message_id: Идентификатор сообщения, отправленного через бота во встроенном режиме, которое является ответом на запрос.