# Проблема с callback_inline telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Есть две функции, в каждой по inline-кнопке, во обеих кнопках значения берется из базы данных.
Одна функция выдает рандомное значение от 0 - call.data, вторая выводит call.data.
 Как указать обработчику в каком случае вывести рандомное значение, а в каком значение?

PyTelegramBotAPI( telebot )
Python3

Comment: Тут бы код увидеть...

Comment: Зачем код?я описал проблему лучше чем сам код.
Если вы не понимаете суть проблемы, то код вам тут не поможет.

Comment: Хорошо, смотри: 
1. Объявляешь переменную
2. В нее рандом от 0 до call.data
3. call.data должна быть конвертирована в int
3.1. Если call.data не является числом,а ,например, буквами, то лучше использовать try - except
4. В функции, где рандом, объявить глобальную переменную и в нее вписать получившиеся данные(можно все сократить там, но Вы же без кода хотите)
5. В другой функции просто выводить call.data
6. Сделать условие(if, else), при котором выводится рандом от 0 до call.data или сама/сам call.data
Вот вам решение проблемы без кода. Как Вы и просили.